# Preseed Ubuntu18 partition doesn't work UEFI

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, uefi

- I am setting up dual boot, Windows and Ubuntu 18.04, for our computer labs (more than 40 computers).
- We successfully set this up with an auto installer before. We re-image the machines with MDT and there is a task sequence to provide an empty partition for linux to use.
- In the past the preseed file we made succesfully found that partition and used the max amount of space available.
- We have all new computers now that HAVE to be run as UEFI. (No way around this long story).
- I ran the auto installer I built and it didn't work. So I realized that I now have to reference the kickstarter and preseed file from grub.cfg and no longer txt.cfg. That worked!
- There is only one thing that is NOT working and is perplexing me:
- ***TLDR*** The partition options in the preseed for finding the max free space aren't working. Instead it gobbles up the entire disk drive for linux. :(
- Link to my preseed: http://ada.evergreen.edu/~tc_michelle/anbrew.seed

  d-i partman-auto/method string regular

  d-i partman-lvm/device_remove_lvm boolean true

  d-i partman-md/device_remove_md boolean true

  d-i partman-lvm/confirm boolean true

  d-i partman-auto/init_automatically_partition select biggest_free

  d-i partman-lvm/confirm_nooverwrite boolean true

  d-i partman-auto/choose_recipe select atomic

  d-i partman-partitioning/confirm_write_new_label boolean true

  d-i partman/choose_partition select finish

  d-i partman/confirm boolean true

  d-i partman/confirm_nooverwrite boolean true

  d-i partman-md/confirm boolean true

  d-i partman-partitioning/confirm_write_new_label boolean true

  d-i partman/choose_partition select finish

  d-i partman/confirm boolean true

  d-i partman/confirm_nooverwrite boolean true

Answer (score 0):

So I found out the culprit/s. I walked through the installation without a preseed and found out I needed to answer one more question:

d-i partman/unmount_active boolean false

I also commented out

d-i partman-auto/method string regular

It works :D